# Upgrading Qt5 to version 5.6.2 throws error

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5, qt5.6

I recently updated my ubuntu system and Qt5 library was updated to version 5.6.2
I had an existing ui file which was being used in my python file as :

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        print("into init")
        uic.loadUi('main.ui',self)
        print("loaded main.ui")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.reset())
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.submit())      
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

But now `uic.loadUi('main.ui',self)` gives a segmentation fault.

I tried opening the ui file in designer and it opened with the following error

```
 Error while reparenting!
Designer: A class name mismatch occurred when creating a widget using the custom widget factory registered for widgets of class KDialog. It returned a widget of class QDialog.
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'SelectionBehavior' for property 'QTabBar::selectionBehaviorOnRemove'
appmenu-qt: registerWindow 206 "&File"
appmenu-qt: registerWindow 206 "&Edit"
appmenu-qt: registerWindow 206 "F&orm"
appmenu-qt: registerWindow 206 "&View"
appmenu-qt: registerWindow 206 "&Settings"
appmenu-qt: registerWindow 206 "&Window"
appmenu-qt: registerWindow 206 "&Help"
```

NOTE : the ui file **does open as it is supposed to** but I am not able to load it from my python function and get a `Segmentation Fault`

Comment: How have you updated PyQt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc i did a apt-get update. any other specific thing i should do ?

Comment: How have you installed PyQt5? Have you used apt-get for it or have you used pip ?, gives more detail, I also recommend reinstalling PyQt5, and if the problem persists report it as a bug to ubuntu.

Comment: On the other hand `sudo apt-get update` does not modify any package, it only updates the list of repositories so you should not have problems, another thing is `sudo apt-get upgrade` that does update the packages.

Comment: `sudo pip3 install pyqt5 --upgrade` returns Requirements already up-to-date

Comment: @eyllanesc i did install it via pip

Comment: remove it and reinstall it. Another option is to remove your PyQt5 and install it from the ubuntu repositories: `sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5`

Comment: `python-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4).
python-pyqt5 set to manually installed.`

Comment: Have you removed the packages first?

Comment: Use `sudo pip3 uninstall pyqt5 && sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

Comment: @eyllanesc now my script doesn't execute at all and gives a segmentation fault. Perhaps in the `from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets,uic`